# How can I fold rdlc code in XML view in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, rdlc, fold

I'm trying to track down a problem in my rdlc file by looking it over in the XLM/Code view. To make things easier, I was hoping to collapse the sections that I can overlook but it doesn't have any collapsible sections, it's treated like flat text. I either have to temporarily rename the file to .xml or copy everything over to notepad++.

Is there something I'm overlooking or am I stuck with workarounds?

Comment: thank u .. it works

Comment: What you could do is to right click on the rdlc file, select open with, from the popup windows select add... browse to notepad++ folder and select its exe, click ok and temporary set it as default. so even if you doubleclick the file from VS i will open the rdlc with notepad ++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Raphael, your comment lead me in the right direction. The solution I was looking for is simply right-clicking the rdlc file inside the Solution Explorer and selecting the "XML (Text) Editor". After you open it with this, View Code starts opening the file with collapsible nodes every time until you use Open With and use something that doesn't do text folding.